# How to access a folder as root?

Tags: root, directory

I want to open a folder in desktop as root and install .jar file in that folder.

I have a ".jar" file in desktop that I need to open it as root user but I want to copy that file into a folder in desktop and then open it as root user. How can I access .jar file in that folder via terminal?

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you think you need root privileges for that? You can create the folder, write a script which runs something like `java -jar file.jar` (make the script executable), and then add the folder (which contaings your script) to your PATH in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: What you describe should not need root privileges. Please edit your question and explain why. What do you mean by install .jar file? What happens when you type `java -jar file.jar` or `sudo java -jar file.jar`?

Comment: I have a ".jar" file in desktop that I need to open it as root user but I want to copy that file into a folder in desktop and then open it as root user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you have:

```
~/Desktop/freedom-folder:
  freedom.jar
  <other files>
```

And you want to run `freedom.jar` as root.

---

## If you want to do it via the terminal

Just open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) then

```
cd ~/Desktop/freedom-folder
sudo java -jar freedom.jar
```

---

## If you want to have a launcher for `yourfreedom` in the Dash

### 1: Open a terminal

Run the following commands:

```
mkdir  ~/bin
cp  ~/Desktop/freedom-folder/freedom.jar  ~/bin
sudo  apt-get  install  gksu
```

The first two lines will create a folder called `bin` in your home folder and
move your `.jar` file into it. The last line is to install `gksu` a GUI frontend for `su`.

### 2: Open GEdit Text Editor

Write the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

gksudo  java  -jar  ~/bin/freedom.jar
```

Save it to the `bin` folder you've created in your home folder. I will assume you've named this script as `freedom-as-root` without any file extensions.

Now, still in GEdit, click `File -> Open...` (or click the folder icon). In the file selection dialog, navigate to your home folder and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to make the hidden files visible. Open `.bashrc`. Go to the last line of this file and add the following new line:

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

Save it. (This line in `~/.bashrc` adds `~/bin` to the search path for executables.)

Create a new file and add the following to it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Your Freedom (with root privileges)
Icon=/home/your-username/.icons/freedom.svg
Exec=/home/your-username/bin/freedom-as-root
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;
```

Save it in your home folder as `freedom-as-root.desktop`. (Instead of `your-username` make sure to type your *actual* username!)

## 3: Open a terminal again

Before, opening the terminal download this [icon](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Peace_dove_icon.svg), by clicking the image and `Save as...` or the like. Save it as `freedom.svg` to your home folder.

(If you wish you can get some other *free/libre* icon from the internet, Wikipedia is a good source for these.)

Go to a terminal again and type:

```
chmod  +x  ~/bin/freedom-as-root
mkdir  ~/.icons
mv  ~/freedom.svg  ~/.icons
mkdir ~/.local/share/applications
mv  ~/freedom-as-root.desktop  ~/.local/share/applications
```

## 4: See if this worked

Just open the Dash and type `your freedom` to see if there were any problems.
The icon should appear in the Dash, and when you click it `gksu` should ask for your password.

Due to an extra step in part (2), now you can also type `freedom-as-root` in the terminal and it will be enough to run `yourfreedom` with privileges.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Edwin thank you very much, your answer helped me. Edvin if I want to have a launcher for this in the Dash what should I do?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include how to add it to the Dash.

Comment: Edvin I fallowed your commands one by one carefully without any error, but when I type "your freedom" in DASH, a white paper without your ".svg" icon is apeared that is inactive. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Please check the following: **(1)** `ls -l ~/bin` shows a line containing `-rwx****** freedom-as-root` (where the asterisks don't matter) and another containing `freedom.jar`. **(2)** `ls ~/.local/share/applications` shows the file `freedom-as-root.desktop`. **(3)** `ls ~/.icons` shows `freedom.svg`. And **(4)** in `~/Desktop/freedom-folder` there aren't any other files related to `yourfreedom` (if this is the case please copy them to `~/bin` and check again).

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo
```

fill in your password

```
cd your-directory
cp path-to-jar/file.jar ./
sudo -k
```

or

```
gksu nautilus
```

then you can do it graphically. That said, why do you think you need to be root to install a jar in you own home folder?

Comment: What does the command `sudo -k`?

Comment: It makes sure that you have to type your password again next time you use sudo ( just to be safe actually).

Comment: I use this command to open .jar file in desktop:1) cd ~/Desktop 2)~/Desktop$ sudo java -jar freedom.jar. But I want to copy .jar file to folder in desktop, and then open it as root.

Comment: This is the proper answer to the original question. But you @Alex, may wish to reword your question in order to say what you mention in your last comment: You "want to copy .jar file to folder in desktop, and then open it as root". We must say that copying the file as root WON'T allow you to open it as root by simply double clicking on it. Your original question seems different than your actual needs.

Comment: ok. I have an antifilter program with Yourfreedom name (freedom.jar). I need to run freedom.jar file as root to enabling ECHO mode in the yourfreedom configuration. My .jar file is in desktop, but I have copied the .jar file into a folder in desktop and now I want to open .jar file via terminal as root.

Answer (score 0):

Run `gksudo nautilus DIR` (DIR being the directory the file is stored in) to open the folder as root.

Comment: No one should not use sudo graphically use gksu as I mentionned above.

Comment: Sorry. That was an accident. Thanks for the reminder.